# CSS table tr hover one color/border and td hover another color/border without important

Tags: css, hover, css-tables, tablerow

I have the following [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/TR8Zg/3/).

Edit: with row boarder style be applied:

```
table,th,td
{
    border:2px solid black;
    border-collapse:collapse;
}
tr:hover td
{
    background-color:grey;
    border-top: 2px solid rgb(10, 0, 255);
    border-bottom: 2px solid rgb(10, 0, 255);
}
td:hover
{
    background-color:rgb(214,214,214) !important;
    border:2px solid red !important;
    border-top: 2px solid red;
    border-bottom: 2px solid red;
}
```

What I'm after is highlighting the ROW and CELL. Originally had thought doing sort of cross-hair, but column background coloring would need JavaScript, which I'll avoid for the time being.

On this would like the `ROW:hover` background color darkish and border emphasized.

The `td:hover` then to be a different color, and border emphasized differently.

Checked in Chrome, not checked Firefox.

Issues: need to use `!important`.
Cell border-left and top not coloring to red?

So is there a way to write the CSS not using `important!`, and correct border styling on the TD cell?

Comment: I've removed `!important` from your fiddle and it still works fine for me (chrome) http://jsfiddle.net/TR8Zg/4/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do your original crosshairs idea with just CSS (no Javascript). Use the `::before` and `::after` pseudo-elements for highlighting. There's a slight issue with Firefox with this method, so I wrote a fix for it.

`border-collapse: collapse` makes borders on `<tds>` behave in strange ways. Instead, put your borders on the `<trs>` and `<cols>`. `border-collapse: collapse` also cuts off edges. To deal with that you have to get creative and draw an extra border on all the outside `<tds>` and `<ths>`. Even stranger, it "eats" a pixel on the top and two pixels on the bottom. So you need `3px` on top to get a `2px` border, and `4px` on bottom to get a `2px` border.

**Demo:** <sub><sub><sub>[image: jsFiddle]</sub></sub></sub>

#### CSS:

```css
table {
    border-collapse: collapse;
    overflow: hidden;
    z-index: 1;
}
td, th, .row, .col, .ff-fix {
    cursor: pointer;
    padding: 10px;
    position: relative;
}
tr:last-child td {
    border-bottom: 4px solid black;
}
tr, col {
    border: 2px solid black;
}
th {
    border-top: 3px solid black;
}
th:last-child, td:nth-child(3n) {
    border-right: 4px solid black;
}
td:first-child, th:first-child {
    border-left: 3px solid black;
}
td:hover {
    border: 2px solid red;
}
td:hover:first-child {
    border-left: 3px solid red;
}
td:hover:nth-child(3n) {
    border-right: 4px solid red;
}
tr:last-child td:hover {
    border-bottom: 4px solid red;
}
td:hover::before,
.row:hover::before,
.ff-fix:hover::before { 
    background-color: #ffa;
    content: '\00a0';  
    height: 100%;
    left: -5000px;
    position: absolute;  
    top: 0;
    width: 10000px;   
    z-index: -1;   
}
td:hover::after,
.col:hover::after,
.ff-fix:hover::after { 
    background-color: #ffa;
    content: '\00a0';  
    height: 10000px;    
    left: 0;
    position: absolute;  
    top: -5000px;
    width: 100%;
    z-index: -1;        
}
```

HTML:

```html
<table>
    <col /><col /><col />
    <tr>
        <th class="col">First Name</th>
        <th class="col">Middle Name</th>
        <th class="col">Last Name</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Peter</td>
        <td>Jeffery</td>
        <td>Griffin</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Lois</td>
        <td>Marie</td>
        <td>Griffin</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Margie</td>
        <td>Ann</td>
        <td>Thatcher</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

#### Script:

```js
function firefoxFix() {
    if ( /firefox/.test( window.navigator.userAgent.toLowerCase() ) ) {
        var tds = document.getElementsByTagName( 'td' ),
            ths = document.getElementsByTagName( 'th' );
        for( var index = 0; index < tds.length; index++ ) {
            tds[index].innerHTML = '<div class="ff-fix">' + tds[index].innerHTML + '</div>';                     
        };
        for( var index = 0; index < ths.length; index++ ) {
            ths[index].innerHTML = 
                  '<div class="' + ths[index].className + '">' 
                + ths[index].innerHTML 
                + '</div>';                     
            ths[index].className = '';
        };
        var style = '<style>'
            + 'td, th { padding: 0 !important; }' 
            + 'td:hover::before, td:hover::after { background-color: transparent !important; }'
            + '</style>';
        document.head.insertAdjacentHTML( 'beforeEnd', style );
    };
};

firefoxFix();
```

Comment: Great - however i can't figure out how to get boarder styled. For row and column - want something like "boarder:2px solid red" for the single cell (td) but for row just "top/bottom...blue" and column "left/right...blue"?

Comment: sorry for late accept - this not 100% quite what wanted - as cell boarder on no hover to be none, then like a Cross Hair highlight background color, AND on specifice cell be one boarder color, on row/column boarders be another color. thanks though for the column highlight

Answer (score 1):

Your example works fine and you don't need to use `!important`. Remove `border-collapse: collapse` and you'll see([jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/TR8Zg/5/)).

Comment: except border style on TR Row not being applied. I tried tr:hover td, then need !important on td:hover to make that style apply http://jsfiddle.net/TR8Zg/6/

Answer (score 1):

Here is a simpler solution: set the following style to all `table`, `tr` and `td`:

```
border: 2px inset black;
border-collapse: collapse;
border-spacing: 0;
```

Making `border` `inset` does the trick. `inset` is useful:

> When both parent and child elements have borders, with this technique you don't get two borders (which looks ugly). This is because child elements are rendered over inset box shadows, not inside inset box shadows.

Reference: http://makandracards.com/makandra/12019-css-emulate-borders-with-inset-box-shadows

Working examples: http://jsfiddle.net/TR8Zg/146/

It is working well on Chrome. But on IE and FireFox the inset effect is populated. So need to find some fixes on them.